# "method ___() in ___ is defined in inaccessible class or interface" compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I found a strange compilation restriction which I cannot explain, and I don't understand this restriction's reason.

**Example-1:**

Consider these classes:

In `package e1;`:

```
public class C1 {
    enum E1 { A, B, C }
    public E1 x;
}
```

In `package e2;`:

```
import e1.C1;
public class C2 {
    public String test(C1 c1) {
        return c1.x.toString();    // here compilation error
    } 
}
```

This causes the following compilation error:

> Error:(5,20) java: `toString()` in `java.lang.Enum` is defined in an inaccessible class or interface

**Example-2:**

Consider these classes:

In `package i1;`:

```
public interface I1 {
    int someMethod();
}

public class C1 {
    static class I2 implements I1 {
        public int someMethod() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    public I2 x = new I2();
}
```

In `package i2;`:

```
import i1.C1;
import i1.I1;
public class C2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        System.out.println(c1.x.someMethod());  // compilation error
    }
}
```

This also causes the same compilation error, but if we change the offending line to:

```
System.out.println(((I1)c1.x).someMethod());
```

Then this can be compiled and works fine.

---

So, the question is:

**Why is this restriction of accessibility needed?**

**Yes, I understand that classes `C1.E` in example-1) and `C1.I2` in example-2) are package private.** But at the same time it's clear that nobody could assign weaker access privileges to methods of a base interface (`I1` of `Object`), so it will be always safe to make direct casting of object to its base interface and get access to restricted method.

Could somebody explain the purposes and the reason of this restriction?

**UPDATE**: [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) pointed out JLS [§6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference (class, interface, or array) type or a constructor of a class type is accessible only if the type is accessible...

Looks like this is the restriction, but it doesn't explain **why** this restriction (in the cases of the above mentioned examples) is needed...

Comment: write `enum E1 { A, B, C }` as `public enum E1 { A, B, C }`

Comment: @Andremoniy The answer is in [#6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) I believe: *A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference (class, interface, or array) type or a constructor of a class type is accessible only **if the type is accessible** and the member or constructor is declared to permit access*.

Comment: @BheshGurung I know, I'm asking: why we need this restriction of accessibility?

Comment: @assylias #6.6.1 looks like exactly that restriction, but it doesn't explains this stupid and unnecessary restriction. Does it?

Comment: @Andremoniy Unfortunately the underlying reason is most likely buried in the head of whoever wrote/decided that (or they just did not think of that specific use case)...

Comment: @assylias I've updated my question, thanks. But I'd like to get some convincing answer and example, which will explain the reason for that.

Comment: Are you asking why accessibility restrictions are needed in general, or why this particular accessibility restriction is necessary?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, about particular.

Comment: I wonder, who and why minused my question on the quiet?

Comment: I think this is pretty reasonable: Default scope is package scope, so you cannot access a variable of an `Enum` with package scope. This restriction should protect this Enum; if no protection is needed, why not doing what Vishal K said?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach the question is about another thing. Particular: why I should cast this reference to `Object` class for invoking `toString()` method, while all objects inheritance `Object` class?

Comment: I think that's the principle of it. It's not a physical protection, but a semantical to prevent errors. In your second case: Users outside this package should not work with `I2` types, only with `I1`s. Imagine a case of providing some Canvas to users: They only see the `Canvas` interface with few methods, but for  internal access and usage, there are other methods with e.g. package scope. You can e.g. see this in DoodleDebug (open source), just look at `DoodleCanvas`(interface) and `RealDoodleCanvas` (server-side implementation).

Comment: @Andremoniy  What was your reason of declaring this as below        enum E1 { A, B, C }
    public E1 x;  Why are you not just declare as public enum E1{A, B, C}.  what was the need for that varaible x.

Comment: @Joe2013 I just want so.

Comment: I think that the answer is buried in the JVM specification. In JLS you can find out what happens, but JVMS gives the answer to why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For invocation of instance methods [invokevirtual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual) instruction is used. To invoke this method class must have a resolved reference to this method

From invokevirtual specification:

> Linking Exceptions
>
> During resolution of the symbolic reference to the method, any of the
>   exceptions pertaining to method resolution (**§5.4.3.3**) can be thrown.

**5.4.3.3**. Method Resolution:

> To resolve an unresolved symbolic reference from D to a method in a
>   class C, the symbolic reference to C given by the method reference is
>   first resolved (**§5.4.3.1**).

**5.4.3.1**. Class and Interface Resolution:

> If C is not accessible (**§5.4.4**) to D, class or interface resolution
>   throws an IllegalAccessError.

**5.4.4**. Access Control:

> A class or interface C is accessible to a class or interface D if and
>   only if either of the following conditions is true:
>
> - C is public.
> - C and D are members of the same run-time package (§5.3).

C and D are not from the same package. So even if java compiles this code for you, it will throw an IllegalAccessError during invocation. Compiler is clever enough to prevent such obvious errors. **These restrictions are coming from requirements of java's class resolution process.**

To invoke instance method JVM requires two things: reference to the object and description of the object(class or interface). Description is accessed through [resolution process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3). If it fails, invocation fails.

> If an error occurs during resolution of a symbolic reference, then an
>   instance of IncompatibleClassChangeError (or a subclass) must be
>   thrown at a point in the program that (directly or indirectly) uses
>   the symbolic reference.

In your case C2 has access to I1. So interface invocation works well. But C2 does not have access to class I2. And that's why IllegalAccessError could be thrown at runtime if this code compiles.

**How to reproduce IllegalAccessError**:

1. Make inner class public and compile all in IDE for example
2. Make inner class package private and compile just it using javac from command line.
3. Replace IDE generated classes with cmd generated
4. And you'll see something like:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to
>   access class
>       qq.Test1$I2 from class Test
>               at Test.main(Test.java:30)

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. Its quite convincing. I'd like to wait for another variants of answer and for another votes for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The access controls (private, protected, public, package) are all well-defined, and give the programmer a lot of flexibility to control the access to classes, variables, methods etc.  Your question just illustrates a particular example of these access controls applying.  The way you've coded up your package `i1`, you've said that it's OK for everyone to see interface `I1`, but that it's not OK for everyone to see class `I2`.  This allows you to add functionality to class `I2` that isn't public, while still allowing access to the bit of `I2` that implements `I1`.  For example, if I add a package local integer to class `I2`

```
public class C1 {
    static class I2 implements I1 {
        int i;
        public int xxx() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    public I2 x = new I2();
}
```

then you've got access to the int within your package but not outside it, and outside your package you can't get around this by casting :-).

Comment: Dear @Stochastically, the question wasn't about **how to find workaround and fix the code**. The question is about: **why I should cast my reference object to `Object` class (for example) to get access to `Object` class methods, while all classes implicitly inheritance `Object` class**.

Comment: @Andremoniy, I didn't fix your code, I came up with an example showing why the rules make sense. The Object class is public, the instance x of class I2 in class C1 is public, so according to the rules of Java, outside the package you are allowed to access x as either (a) an Object, or (b) a class that implements I1. However, because the class definition of I2 is package local, you're not allowed to access it in any other way. So outside the package you can't access the int that I added, and if it were to implement e.g. a package local interface I3 then you couldn't access it as an I3 either.

Answer (score 1):

`E1` from example 1 and `I2` from example 2 are both not visible to the callers in those examples. So it is clear to me, that the compiler says it doesn't know how to handle it. Your intention is ambiguous.
Or put it the other way around: how should the JVM handle such a call to invisible classes? Cast to an interface? Which one, as a class may implement several.

Maybe it would be possible to let the compiler add a cast to its interface in special cases, but it's just that: special cases and not a general rule. Besides that, it would be highly confusing to developers to get an instance of a class which can not be accessed (think of frameworks).

If you want to hide internals, you'd rather use (public) interfaces, instead of package-private implementations.

Comment: they both aren't visible, but both of them do inheritance from `Object` class. So, why I should evidently cast them to `Object` if I want just invoke `toString()` method?

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? You explicitly return an instance of an INVISIBLE type. In Java, it happens that all classes inherit from `Object`, and if you declare the type to be `Object` everything is fine because caller and callee agree on a contract both can see/validate. In your example, you hide those contracts. Although for you it is obvious, that it is the same contract as for `Object`, it isn't for the compiler - it just can't have the same view on it as you have.

Answer (score -1):

I will try explaining it by using your Example 2 and changing it a little bit.

Suppose class `C1` were like this

```
public class C1 {
    static class I2 implements I1 {
        public int xxx() {
            return 1;
        }

        public int hello(){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    public I2 x = new I2();
}
```

I have just added another public method hello() to the class I2.

In

```
package i2;:

import i1.C1;
import i1.I1;
public class C2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C1 c1 = new C1();

        c1.x.hello(); // Will not compile.
        c1.x.toString(); //Will not compile.             

        Object mObject=(Object)c1.x;
        mObject.toString(); //Will compile.
    }
}
```

Now, to answer your question of why the restriction.
The restriction allows the programmer to prevent access to the public methods of class `I2`. Since the access specifier of `I2` is the default access specifier, none of its methods should be available outside the package, hence the restriction.
If the restriction were not there we would have been able to access the method `hello()` from `C2` (which is in a different package) even though `I2` has the default access specifier.

Casting `c1.x` to `Object` works because now the compiler treats it as an object of class `Object`. Hence we can access its `toString()` method. Hence, `mObject.toString()` works whereas
`c1.x.toString()` doesn't becuase class `I2` is not accessible from class `C2`.

Comment: You are talking about obvious things. I'm looking for more deeply analysis and explanation of this restriction. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

In both examples you are using inner classes / interfaces.  Inner classes cannot be accessed by any object outside of the class they are defined in.

Hence, you have to cast them to objects (or any other supertype of your inner class).  You have to do this cast manually because the JDK does not know of any implicit casts.

The way to deal with this is to turn your inner classes into regular classes.  Inner classes are very useful, but only for very specific tasks.

Comment: This is not so.  If an inner class is public, you can access it from another class or package.  If the inner class is `public static`, then it is just like any other class.  If the inner class is `public`, but not static, then you just cannot create a new instance of it from another class, due to lack of scope.