# SomeEnum.values() is defined in an inaccessible class or interface when doing switch over enum

Tags: java, enums

Let's consider the base class:

```java
package base;

public abstract class Base {
    protected enum BaseEnum {
        FIRST, SECOND, THIRD
    }
}
```

And its subclass:

```java
package a;

import base.Base;

public class A {
    // The error message appears in case when NestedA is a nested or inner class
    protected /* static */ class InnerA extends Base {
        protected BaseEnum getEnumA() {
            return BaseEnum.FIRST;
        }

        protected int xxx() {
            BaseEnum enumA = getEnumA();
            switch (enumA) {
            // ^^ base.NestedBase.BaseEnum.values() is defined in an inaccessible class or interface
                case FIRST:
                case SECOND:
                    return 1;
                default:
                    return 2;
            }
        }

        protected int xxx2() {
            BaseEnum enumA = getEnumA();
            if (enumA == BaseEnum.FIRST || enumA == BaseEnum.SECOND) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }
        }

        protected int xxx3() {
            System.out.println(BaseEnum.values());
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

When I am trying to compile it, a compilation error appears on line with switch statement in `xxx()` saying:

`java: base.Base.BaseEnum.values() is defined in an inaccessible class or interface`

Briefly the question is what exactly going on here? Why `values()` is even called here? If it is really called, why is it inaccessible? As you can see, I can properly access `BaseEnum` and its members from this class (see `xxx2()`) and even the `values()` method (which is public method of protected nested enum inside `InnerA` superclass, see `xxx3()`). Is access calculated as if this switch would be inside `A` class? If so, why?

Comment: Similar question, but I don't think it quite explains this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722184/method-in-is-defined-in-inaccessible-class-or-interface-compilation/15810050

Comment: This has been raised as a bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178701 but has not had feedback from the Java maintainers, as far as I can see. So whether it's considered a valid bug is unclear.

Comment: @tgdavies Perhaps you should post your comment as an Answer, to be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been raised as a bug bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178701 but has not had feedback from the Java maintainers, as far as I can see. So whether it's considered a valid bug is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solvings:**

The first solution I found, was that A has to extend from Base, not InnerA. So yout can acces the protected BaseEnum in yout inner class InnerA.

The second solution is simply to make the BaseEnum public.

**Why is this so?**

The switch statement is the problem, as you presumed in your question. But I have neither a clue nor found something why this is a problem for the switch statement to switch through an protected enum in this constellation.